# KSQL extract JSON/AVRO payload into one column

Tags: json, avro, confluent-platform, ksqldb

In KSQL: I'd like to extract the underlying payload with the schema (JSON/AVRO) and add it to a different KSQL stream into one column.

**Example:**

INPUT:

Stream1 = `'{"name":"Ben", "age":30}'`

OUTPUT:

Stream2 = `'{"EventTime":"2021-10-01:00:00:00", "Schema": "JSON", "EventPayLoad": "{"name":"Ben", "age":30}'`

Comment: Do you mean you want to hardcode `"Schema": "JSON"`, or you want to dynamically return the serialisation format of the data?

Comment: I want to dynamically return the serialised format of the data.
Consider the example:


Source Stream 1:
'{"name":"Ben", "age":30}'


Source Stream 2:
'{"carType":"Sedan", "yearModel":2021, "colour":"blue"}'


Output stream should then be:
'
{"EventTime": "2021-10-01:00:00:00", "Payload": "{"name":"Ben", "age":30}"},
{"EventTime": "2021-10-01:00:00:01", "Payload": "{"carType":"Sedan", "yearModel":2021, "colour":"blue"}"}
'

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK ksqlDB does not expose the serialisation format of the stream as a system column (in the way that it does with `ROWTIME` for the timestamp).

I would suggest [logging an issue or writing a KLIP](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/) to propose it.